# Filter an ICollectionView

Tags: c#, icollectionview

I am using an ICollectionView for navigation (.RecordNext, etc), which works perfectly, but I am unable to filter the collection.

CanFilter returns "false", but I don't know why or what to do?

```
ICollectionView myICollectionView = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(EmployeeDataTable);
MessageBox.Show($"CanFilter = {myICollectionView.CanFilter.ToString()}");
```

Comment: Please share the detail about `EmployeeDataTable` in your code.

Comment: nothing special just: (2) System.Int32, (25) System.String's, (3) System.DateTime's. Do you know why a collection would disallow filtering?